# Evaluation of $\int_{e}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{4(x^2-1)- (x^2-1)^{\frac14}2^{-\frac14 }}$

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I tried many ways to evaluate the below integral but i didn't succeed , I have used Hypergeometric functions  but it fails , now My question is the below integral has known closed form ? and how i can evaluate it ?

$$\int_{e}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{4(x^2-1)- (x^2-1)^{\frac14}2^{-\frac14 }}$$

**Note** Wolfram alpha show that is a positive integrand as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral((dx)%2F(4(x%C2%B2-1)-2%5E(-1%2F4)(x%C2%B2-1)%5E(1%2F4))),+x%3D+e+to+pi)

Comment: I highly doubt it has a closed form.